# Memory limitations in VS 2010 with c++ or just another bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory

I got a program which uses a lot for memory for computations. Not too much, I guess. All bif arrays are stored at heap, of cause. MS VS 10 is my IDE. Task manager in Windows says it takes 1548 Kb. I am still writing it, and at some point I added

```
bool* mask= new bool [numberOfUnknowns];
```

and `numberOfUnknowns` is about `1600`. It is in the public method of one of the classes (not sure if it matters). And I get

> Unhandled exception at 0x777615de in ProgrammName.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x006a2000.

at this line. And it works with hard-coded

```
new bool [10];
```

and fails with

```
new bool [1600];
```

So, am I reaching possible memory size? Or should I check something else? I don't believe that I can't get more memory because putting

```
double* a = new double [100000];
```

in the main just for check makes memory size greater but the run-time error is on the same position.
Thanks in advance.

**Addition 1:**

I put the call of method that contains this line before all other calls and it worked. So, I guess, it's memory issue because of some memory allocated/freed during the work of other methods  of my class. So, how is it possible? Should I post some more code or there is a common solution/description for such cases?

**Addition 2:** And for `std::vector` - need to find out what's wrong now, don't want to leave this problem without understanding.
Thanks for style correction of the post!

Comment: Show us more of the surrounding code. All the snippets in your question are fine.

Comment: An error message is given, along with a location in code. The error is not an out-of-memory error, it's related to dereferencing a location that you can't access.

Comment: `1600` bools is 1,6 KB, it can't be a memory limitation. Probably you are performing some dubious operation with pointers.

Comment: If your computer can run VS2010, then you definitely have more than 1548 kB of memory.

Comment: @Mysticial I didn't think it's hardware problem :)

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the code you wrote.  The heap got corrupted by some code that ran earlier.  Good luck with that.

Comment: @HansPassant Yep, i found an issue in other method that was called earlier. There was a leak of memory. Can you please make it an answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::vector`. Your error is basically accessing memory you no longer own- either because you already freed it or past the end or something like that. You need to use a class-based solution to prevent this problem.

Comment: As far as there is no answer like "The heap got corrupted by some code that ran earlier" - as was posted at comments, I will accept this answer because it is useful in some way.